# PNG (with transparent background) and \pdfximage \pdfrefximage

Tags: graphics, pdftex

I'm using `pdflatex` (MiKTeX 2.9 portable on Windows 7), and use the pair `\pdfximage` and `\pdfrefximage` to include graphics.

Using a PNG with a transparent background yields, in my view, unexpected behavior.

It appears that the index generated by `\pdfximage` gets corrupted - which makes the "next graphic" unusable. But the graphic after that ones *can* be used.

I hope my example below illustrates what's happening on my machine:

Is this correct usage, or am I not using the `pdflatex` primitives correctly?

```
% SAMPLE
\pdfoutput=1 
\documentclass[german]{article} 
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry} 
\usepackage{babel} 
% ------------------------------------------ 
% When the following line is used, \LOGOiii yields 'my_other_pic.jpg' - which is not correct.
\pdfximage width 20.0mm height 8.0mm {png_transparent_bg.png} 

% When replacing the above with either of the following lines, \LOGOiii yields 'my_cool_pic.jpg' - which is correct
% (but then I don't have my logo with transparent background)
%\pdfximage width 20.0mm height 8.0mm {my_pic.png}   % png without transparent background
%\pdfximage width 20.0mm height 8.0mm {png_transparent_bg.jpg}  % jpg - no transparent background

\newcommand{\LOGOi}{\pdfrefximage1}

% If png_transparent_bg.png is used, attempting to reference this image results the error:
%     ! pdfTeX error (ext1): cannot find referenced object. (but pdfrefximage3 works!)
\pdfximage height 28.0mm             {my_other_pic.png} 
\newcommand{\LOGOii}{\pdfrefximage2}

\pdfximage height 20.0mm             {my_cool_pic.png} 
\newcommand{\LOGOiii}{\pdfrefximage3}  % 

\begin{document} 
\noindent This pdf illustrates behavior diferences between 'loading' a png graphic     with transparent background as first graphic - via pdfximage.
{\LOGOiii}
{\LOGOii}  % comment to remove compile error
\rule{-15mm}{0mm}
{\LOGOi}
\end{document} 
\endinput
```

Console output (attempts to reference 2nd graphic object) - error:

```
>h:\MikTeXTest\MikTeX.2.9p\texmf\miktex\bin\pdflatex -aux-directory=h:\temp\pdflatex --enable-write18 test_pdfxrefimage.tex 
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12 (MiKTeX 2.9)
entering extended mode
(Q:\TA ... \TST\test_pdfxrefimage\test_pdfxrefimage.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
... console output deleted ...

)) (h:\temp\pdflatex\test_pdfxrefimage.aux)
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
! pdfTeX error (ext1): cannot find referenced object.
<to be read again> 
               }
l.27 {\LOGOii}
                % uncomment for error
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on h:/temp/pdflatex/test_pdfxrefimage.log.
>Exit code: 1
```

Below is console output from pdflatex with above code,
but commented line:

```
%{\LOGOii}  % comment to remove compile error
```

compiles ok - but references wrong graphic:

```
>h:\MikTeXTest\MikTeX.2.9p\texmf\miktex\bin\pdflatex -aux-directory=h:\temp\pdflatex --enable-write18 test_pdfxrefimage.tex 
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12 (MiKTeX 2.9)
entering extended mode
(Q:\TA ... \TST\test_pdfxrefimage\test_pdfxrefimage.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
... console output deleted ...

)) (h:\temp\pdflatex\test_pdfxrefimage.aux)
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex

Overfull \hbox (11.66379pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 24--28
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 This pdf illustrates behavior diferences between 'loading' a pn
g graphic with transparent background
[1{h:/MikTeXTest/MikTeX.2.9p/localtexmf/fonts/map/pdftex/pdftex.map} <Q:/TA.../TST/test_pdfxrefimage/my_other_pic.png (PNG copy)> <Q:/TA.../TST/test_pdfxrefimage/png_transparent_bg.png>]
(h:\temp\pdflatex\test_pdfxrefimage.aux) )
(see the transcript file for additional information)<h:/MikTeXTest/MikTeX.2.9p/
texmf/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on test_pdfxrefimage.pdf (1 page, 33610 bytes).
Transcript written on h:/temp/pdflatex/test_pdfxrefimage.log.
>Exit code: 0
```

References "my_other_pic.png" but should actually use "my_cool_pic.png".

Comment: I'm not sure why you want to use the primitives rather than the higher level `\includegraphics`.

Comment: @egreg: Because pain is soo much fun. `:-)`

Comment: fyi:Because I inherited gobs of pdftex files. Also, the first place I look for pdftex documentation is, oddly enough, in the pdftex documentation - not in the more general 'graphics package' documentation. Maybe a question here is the general one of: "where do I look for an answer and how do I determine I found the best solution out of what I currently know and don't know?" There are a lot of ways to do simular tasks in TeX/LaTeX.

Comment: The motivation is understandable; I'll add to my answer based on the new information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The obvious problem is that the generated number is *not* 2 for the second image, as a simple

```
\showthe\pdflastximage
```

put just after

```
\pdfximage height 28.0mm             {my_other_pic.png}
```

will show:

```
> 3.
l.18 \showthe\pdflastximage
```

This is probably due to the fact that one more picture object is included for "masking" the one with transparent background.

There is another primitive, `\pdflastximage` that can (and should) be used for these situations: it is a read-only integer that is loaded with the number assigned to the last object included with `\pdfximage`. However you *can't* say

```
\newcommand{\LOGOi}{\pdfrefximage\pdflastximage}
```

because this would *always* refer to the last image. Some lower level trickery is needed:

```
\pdfximage width 20.0mm height 8.0mm {png_transparent_bg.png} 
\edef\LOGOi{\pdfrefximage\the\pdflastximage\relax}

\pdfximage height 28.0mm             {my_other_pic.png} 
\edef\LOGOii{\pdfrefximage\the\pdflastximage\relax}

\pdfximage height 20.0mm             {my_cool_pic.png} 
\edef\LOGOiii{\pdfrefximage\the\pdflastximage\relax}
```

Each `\edef` will expand `\the\pdflastximage` to the current value; in your case, the expansions of `\LOGOi`, `\LOGOii` and `\LOGOiii` will be

```
> \LOGOi=macro:
->\pdfrefximage 1\relax .

> \LOGOii=macro:
->\pdfrefximage 3\relax .

> \LOGOiii=macro:
->\pdfrefximage 4\relax .
```

as required for a correct later usage of the images.

It's quite unclear why you don't want to use the higher level `\includegraphics` for this. If you're afraid that multiply used pictures are included multiple times in the PDF file, don't be.

---

In case you've inherited some document where these low level tricks are used, just comment out the lines and change them according to this model

```
%\pdfximage width 20.0mm height 8.0mm {png_transparent_bg.png} 
%\edef\LOGOi{\pdfrefximage\the\pdflastximage\relax}
%\pdfximage height 28.0mm             {my_other_pic.png} 
%\edef\LOGOii{\pdfrefximage\the\pdflastximage\relax}
%\pdfximage height 20.0mm             {my_cool_pic.png} 
%\edef\LOGOiii{\pdfrefximage\the\pdflastximage\relax}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand\LOGOi{\includegraphics[width 20.0mm, height 8.0mm]{png_transparent_bg.png}}
\newcommand{\LOGOii}{\includegraphics[height 28.0mm]{my_other_pic.png}}
\newcommand{\LOGOiii}{\includegraphics[height 20.0mm]{my_cool_pic.png}}
```

Comment: Thanks a million egreg and Alexg. As you both write, using the hardcoded index caused the problem. Using `\edef` to replace `\newcommand` with `\pdflastximage` works.

Answer (score 5):

Never use `\pdfrefximage` with a hard coded PDF object number. The correct syntax is:

```
\pdfrefximage\pdflastximage
```

Of course, you may store the PDF object number generated by `\pdfximage` in a macro for later use. However you cannot not use `\newcommand` for that, because `\pdflastximage` must be expanded during macro definition:

```
\edef\LOGOobjI{\the\pdflastximage}
```

or (global macro definition, visible outside groups)

```
\xdef\LOGOobjI{\the\pdflastximage}
```

Later use looks like this:

```
\pdfrefximage\LOGOobjI
```

See [egregs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg) comment below. He proposes a macro for `\LOGOi` which exactly meets your expectations.

Comment: One could say `\xdef\LOGOi{\pdfrefximage\the\pdflastximage\relax}` so `\LOGOi` would directly include the image.

Comment: @egreg: Ok. I wasn't sure whether `\pdfrefximage` would insert the image into the page stream during `\xdef` execution.

Comment: It's safe: `\xdef` only does expansion of the given replacement text, not execution. Since `\pdfrefximage` is unexpandable, nor is `\relax` this is equivalent to say `\def\LOGOi{\pdfrefximage 1\relax}` (assuming that 1 is the number assigned to the object). The `\relax` is needed in case one writes `\LOGOi 2` which, without `\relax`, would look for `\pdfrefximage12`; `\relax` stops the search for digits.

Comment: Thanks both egreg and AlexG for your answers. I put egregs answer below as the answer - even though the above answer and comments also solve the problem.